# Master page Header

Tags: 2013, javascript, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I wish to customize my **master page**, 
just adding a simple **header** and removing the standarda SharePoint toolbars.
How can I do it easly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML master pages in 2013.

1. Download starter HTML master page from http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/releases/view/97062
2. Browse to your publishing site.
3. In the upper-right corner of the page, choose Settings, and then choose Design Manager.
4. In Design Manager, in the left navigation pane, choose Edit Master Pages.
5. Choose Convert an HTML file to a SharePoint master page.
6. In the Select an Asset dialog box, browse to and select the HTML file that you want to convert.
7. Choose Insert.
8. Follow the link in the Status column to preview the file and to view any errors or warnings about the master page.

Now your new master page is ready.

[Understanding the HTML file after conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370(v=office.15).aspx#Understand)

Now you can work on the converted HTML file to add/edit style/placeholders etc.

**For removing Ribbon**

1. Open the converted HTML file in SharePoint Designer 2013
2. Add following CSS

   ```
   #s4-ribbonrow, #suiteBar { display : none; }
   ```